# Take argument that implements several Interfaces for object creation

Tags: java, interface, implementation, guice

I have object that I want to create using object that implements two interfaces (suppose, I can't modify object's class to create third interface that will be extends two interfaces). What will be the best way to create such objects using guice?

Comment: You want to create an instance of a class which implements 2 interfaces using guice? Or did I misinterpret the question?

Comment: @extraneon, Yeah. I want to inject such object to my class. Before this I should create such object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java does allow you to do interface combinations, i.e.

```
static class TL<T extends IA & IB> extends TypeLiteral<T>(){}
```

but you'll notice there really has to be a concrete type T which implements both of these interfaces. Java can't invent "combination types" for variables - a type must exist with an actual class file.

I was surprised to discover that it is indeed possible to do this. I suspect this is a dark corner that Guice's maintainers would suggest not going into, and it is probably not a good idea.

Things to notice about the code below:

- I am actually abusing Guice's built-in safeguards by making TL subclass TypeLiteral parameterized on IA instead of TypeLiteral on T which would be correct.  So in fact, this entire example probably works by accident.
- It doesn't help that much.  Something, somewhere finally has to specify a concrete type (the class Both) in this case.  It lets you get around specifying a concrete type in the classes which *use* the object, but not when you bind it or if you request it directly from the injector
- Almost nobody understands the TypeA & TypeB syntax with Java generics - prepare for anybody who looks at this code to be completely baffled, even some Java gurus
- If you later try to use an object which only implements *one* of the interfaces, you *could* create a dynamic proxy which implements one interface and delegates to the object, but you will still need to create an interface which combines the two to give Java a type to refer to

public class X {

```
static final class TL<T extends IA & IB> extends TypeLiteral<IA> {}

interface IA {}
interface IB {}
static final class Both implements IA, IB {}

@Test
public void test() {
    Injector inj = Guice.createInjector(new M());
    Both object = inj.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<Both>(){}));
    assertNotNull(object);
    Foo<Both> foo = inj.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<Foo<Both>>() {}));
    assertTrue (object instanceof IA);
    assertTrue (object instanceof IB);
    assertNotNull(foo);
    assertNotNull(foo.obj);
}

static class Foo<T extends IA & IB> {
    private final T obj;
    @Inject
    Foo(T obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}

static class M extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(new TL<Both>()).to(Both.class);
    }
}
}
```

So I think the answer is, you can but you probably shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

Either inject one interface and cast to the other when needed or inject the same object twice as two different interfaces.

Both are ugly, I know, but I'd call the whole approach ugly. If you need two different interfaces a single class implements you probably haw a flaw in your object model. If one class implements two disjoint interfaces it has two different aspects and you should probably improve it's [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: +1. Probably you are right. It's not production project and I decided to try some different stuff, and probably went to wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do:

```
// Your original class
class AB implements IA, IB {...}

// In a Module
bind(AB.class).in(SOMESCOPE);
bind(IA.class).to(AB.class);
bind(IB.class).to(AB.class);

// In the object to be inejcted with AB
class MyClass {
    @Inject IA a;
    @Inject IB b;
}
```

In the end, you would actually have `a == b`, wouldn't that fit the bill?

Comment: I just saw that my answer actually maps to Sean's answer, it just show some actual code.

Comment: +1, But I wouldn't use it, because I think field injection shouldn't be used in projects, only in examples. Going by this solution it would be better to use setters.

Comment: Yes of course, I used field injection here for the sake of showing a small snippet; the main idea being to inject IA and IB as 2 different instances (although they are the same).